# How to set an imageView to square view in android?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I wanna to create an app that view an image/poster, I want the imageView in square. Before this, i try to get the screen width and assign it to image height and width, something like this

```
Bitmap newicon = Bitmap.CreateBitmap (int x, int y, int width, int height, matrix, false/true);
```

But there is an error occur "x + width <= bitmap.width()". This is the example that i create so far, but i set the height to 400dp. I want the height and width is flexible depend on phone size. Any ideas?

```
<ImageView
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:id="@+id/ivPoster" />
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should handle this using only XML, because if you have a lot of pictures in your listview and you create a new Bitmap for each of them, you risk an out of memory exception which can crash your app... I think your current XML is ok, but you will not get a square image for each device if you fix the height and not the width. One way of getting a square image for each device, for example, is to get the width of your screen programmatically and then set your ImageView width and height.

Comment: have you tried  `android:scaleType="fitXY"`. and you want to fit to sqare then you need to remove margins from imageview I guess.

Comment: android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: is this just a one image or a single row of listview ?

Comment: @lcw_gg ah okay, i will try to set the width. thanks man;

Comment: @DavidJhons im using cardview and recyclerview. bharat, chirag i've done that. but i want it to centerFit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use custom imageview for this, take a look at this:

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {
    public SquareImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth()); // Snap to width
    }
}
```

Use it instead of ImageView in your layout file.

Hope this helped!

Comment: You also can use android:scaleType options in this.

Comment: Oh thanks man! Once i create this class, how can i use it? How can i send the variable that hold the image to the class. Or it auto get it? A bit blur sorry

Comment: Just replace <ImageView> with <yourpackagepath.SquareImageView> and height wrap_content.

Comment: eh i getting this error Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.rocky.posterView.SquareImageView. Cannot inflate.

Comment: Okay got it! I just change the packagepath to my namespace. Thanks again!